# Conversion error from database smallint into C# nullable int

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a security_role_cd column in database of `smallint` datatype. I am selecting this column using following code into a `nullable int` variable.

I am getting following error:

> Error     3       Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'short'

What is the correct code to overcome this error?

```
SELECT R.security_role_cd  FROM Security_Role R WHERE security_role_name = 'Admin'
```

C#

```
        int? roleID = null;
        string commandText = "SELECT R.security_role_cd  FROM Security_Role R WHERE security_role_name = @roleName";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleName",roleName);
        SqlDataReader readerRole = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerRole.HasRows)
        {
            while (readerRole.Read())
            {
                roleID = readerRole.GetInt16(0) == 0 ? null : readerRole.GetInt16(0) ;

            }
        }
        readerRole.Close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just needs to know how to *type* the `null`:

```
roleID = readerRole.GetInt16(0) == 0 ? (int?)null : (int)readerRole.GetInt16(0);
```

Personally I'd cache the value though:

```
int tmp = readerRole.GetInt16(0); // implicit widening to int here
roleID = tmp == 0 ? (int?)null : tmp;
```

Although I'd also call into doubt the wisdom of turning a `0` into a `null` - better to use `IsDBNull` - something like:

```
if(reader.IsDBNull(0)) {
    roleID = null;
} else {
    roleID = (int)readerRole.GetInt16(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
roleID = readerRole.GetInt16(0) == 0 ? (int?) null : readerRole.GetInt16(0) ;
```

According to the documentation of ternary operator, the data type on either side of the colon (:) has to be the same. As you had it without casting, the type of null could not be determined (i.e. if nullable int, or null string, or null object)

**Update**

```
roleID = readerRole.GetInt16(0) == 0 ? (int?) null : readerRole.GetInt32(0) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I ran into another datatype problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306275/datatype-returned-varies-based-on-data-in-table/13306322#comment18147151_13306322