# Exception when AddWithValue parameter is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have following code for specifying parameters for SQL query. I am getting following exception when I use `Code 1`; but works fine when I use `Code 2`. In `Code 2` we have a check for null and hence a `if..else` block.

Exception:

> *The parameterized query '(@application_ex_id nvarchar(4000))SELECT  E.application_ex_id A' expects the parameter '@application_ex_id', which was not supplied.*

**Code 1**:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", logSearch.LogID);
```

**Code 2**:

```
if (logSearch.LogID != null)
{
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", logSearch.LogID);
}
else
{
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", DBNull.Value );
}
```

**QUESTION**

1. Can you please explain why it is unable to take NULL from logSearch.LogID value in Code 1 (but able to accept DBNull)?
2. Is there a better code to handle this?

**Reference**:

1. [Assign null to a SqlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555935/how-to-assign-null-to-a-sqlparameter)
2. [Datatype returned varies based on data in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306275/datatype-returned-varies-based-on-data-in-table)
3. [Conversion error from database smallint into C# nullable int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265704/conversion-error-from-database-smallint-into-c-sharp-nullable-int?lq=1)
4. [What is the point of DBNull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488727/what-is-the-point-of-dbnull/9632050#9632050)

CODE

```
    public Collection<Log> GetLogs(LogSearch logSearch)
    {
        Collection<Log> logs = new Collection<Log>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string commandText = @"SELECT  *
                FROM Application_Ex E 
                WHERE  (E.application_ex_id = @application_ex_id OR @application_ex_id IS NULL)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                //Parameter value setting
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", logSearch.LogID);
                if (logSearch.LogID != null)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", logSearch.LogID);
                }
                else
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id", DBNull.Value );
                }

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        Collection<Object> entityList = new Collection<Object>();
                        entityList.Add(new Log());

                        ArrayList records = EntityDataMappingHelper.SelectRecords(entityList, reader);

                        for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Log log = new Log();
                            Dictionary<string, object> currentRecord = (Dictionary<string, object>)records[i];
                            EntityDataMappingHelper.FillEntityFromRecord(log, currentRecord);
                            logs.Add(log);
                        }
                    }

                    //reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return logs;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? Code 2 is the correct way to send a null value to a database.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Annoying, isn't it.

You can use:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id",
       ((object)logSearch.LogID) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Or alternatively, use a tool like "dapper", which will do all that messing for you.

For example:

```
var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(commandText,
      new { application_ex_id = logSearch.LogID }).ToList();
```

I'm *tempted* to add a method to dapper to get the `IDataReader`... not really sure yet whether it is a good idea.

Comment: @Phil indeed; most things can... but I don't like adding extension methods on `object`, and we can't see whether that is `Nullable<T>` vs `string`, etc... but yes: it could be done easily enough.

Comment: I was thinking an extension on the `Parameters` property - is that an `Object`?

Comment: @Phil hmmm, yes it is, and I see what you mean... maybe `AddWithValueAndTreatNullTheRightDamnedWay(...)`

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please explain why it is unable to take NULL from logSearch.LogID value in Code 1 (but able to accept DBNull)?

Comment: @Lijo because `null` in a parameter value means "don't send this parameter". I suspect it was a bad decision that simply got baked in. In fact, I think **most** of `DBNull` was a fundamentally bad decision that got baked in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632050/23354

Comment: Why is there the need to put `(object)` before `logSearch.LogID` here?

Comment: @tylerH because of the null coale cast rules - which may be weakening in C#9

Answer (score 62):

I find it easier to just write an extension method for the `SqlParameterCollection` that handles null values:

```
public static SqlParameter AddWithNullableValue(
    this SqlParameterCollection collection,
    string parameterName,
    object value)
{
    if(value == null)
        return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
    else
        return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
}
```

Then you just call it like:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue(key, value);
```

Comment: _value_ can be **int or int?, string, bool or bool?, DateTime or Datetime?**, etc ?

Comment: I read Marc's answer and thought "I think I'd rather just write an extension method for the Parameters collection", then I scrolled down a hair... (nice thing about an extension method is that I can do a single find/replace after and all my code updates are done)

Comment: Great solution...Extension methods must be defined in a static class.
[How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method)

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken (kind of a C# newbie) but couldn't you do it more concisely like this: `return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, value ?? DBNull.Value);`

Comment: @TobiasFeil Yes, you could do that too. It's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Works with VB.NET as well after applying the `<Extension()>` attribute

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you're doing this while calling a stored procedure: I think it's easier to read if you declare a default value on the parameter and add it only when necessary.

SQL:

```sql
DECLARE PROCEDURE myprocedure
    @myparameter [int] = NULL
AS BEGIN
```

C#:

```c#
int? myvalue = initMyValue();
if (myvalue.hasValue) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("myparamater", myvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

some problem, allowed with Necessarily set SQLDbType

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
command.Parameters.Value=DBNull.Value
```

where SqlDbType.NVarChar you type. Necessarily set SQL type.