# Inserting NULL into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to create an `INSERT INTO` query, that which creates a value in a table with the value null; however, this is not working.

This is the code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Student_ID],[Teacher_ID],[Question],[Answer],[Answered]) VALUES (@Student_ID,@Teacher_ID,@Question,@Answer,@Answered)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", FrmLogIn.User_ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_ID", cmboxTeacherChoice.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", tbStudentQuestion.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", null);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answered", 0);
```

This code works when a value is put in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", null);` instead of null being there, but I need this value to be null. In the database this variable is saved as a `nvarchar(MAX)` and is allowed nulls, am I doing something incorrect? Please let me know.

Any answers are appreciated, if I was unclear please inform me, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception when AddWithValue parameter is NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451085/exception-when-addwithvalue-parameter-is-null)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: IF this value will always be _null_, why are you putting into the `INSERT`, you could just remove it from the statement and then not add the corresponding parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`